# pip3 cannot determine archive format - atlasplots installation

Tags: python, pip

i am trying to install Atlas Plots, but i am getting some errors. I tried to install it with the following command line:

```
pip3 install https://github.com/joeycarter/atlas-plots
```

But when i run it, terminal shows me the following error:

> Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-req-build-o2c8xrmg

And this command line is the only option available in the installation tutorial on the software site, which is:

> https://atlas-plots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installing-atlasplots

And i need this atlasplots in my research, so i would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct syntax to install from a Github repo are:

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/joeycarter/atlas-plots.git#egg=atlasplots"
```

or

```
pip install "git+ssh://git@github.com/joeycarter/atlas-plots.git#egg=atlasplots"
```

See the docs at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#vcs-support

Report the problem at https://github.com/joeycarter/atlas-plots/issues or better send a pull request fixing https://github.com/joeycarter/atlas-plots/blob/master/docs/getting_started.rst